# How can I transform this Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that just contains the last 14 days of the week and each with an integer value.  I would like to combine the values of each day of the week like below.

Here is my dataframe:

```
    Day     Total
0   Tue     66
1   Wed     54
2   Thu     47
3   Fri     60
4   Sat     41
5   Sun     44
6   Mon     73
7   Tue     67
8   Wed     51
9   Thu     56
10  Fri     47
11  Sat     42
12  Sun     43
13  Mon     46
```

...and I would like it to look like this...

```
    Day     Total1  Total2
0   Tue     66      67
1   Wed     54      51
2   Thu     47      56
3   Fri     60      47
4   Sat     41      42
5   Sun     44      43
6   Mon     73      46
```

so that each day has two values rather than one.

Is there a fancy method to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First compare first value of `Day` selected by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) with column `Day` and with [`cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) create new column. Then use [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html), last add [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html):

```
df['col'] = df['Day'].eq(df['Day'].iat[0]).cumsum()
df = df.pivot(index='Day', columns='col', values='Total').add_prefix('Total')
print (df)

col  Total1  Total2
Day                
Fri      60      47
Mon      73      46
Sat      41      42
Sun      44      43
Thu      47      56
Tue      66      67
Wed      54      51
```

Another solution:

```
df['col'] = df['Day'].eq(df['Day'].iat[0]).cumsum()
df = df.set_index(['Day', 'col'])['Total'].unstack().add_prefix('Total')
print (df)
col  Total1  Total2
Day                
Fri      60      47
Mon      73      46
Sat      41      42
Sun      44      43
Thu      47      56
Tue      66      67
Wed      54      51
```

If want sort index by `days` need `ordered` [`categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html):

```
days = ['Sun', 'Mon','Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat' ]
df['Day'] = df['Day'].astype('category', categories=days, ordered=True)
df['col'] = df['Day'].eq(df['Day'].iat[0]).cumsum()
df = df.set_index(['Day', 'col'])['Total'].unstack().add_prefix('Total')
print (df)
col  Total1  Total2
Day                
Sun      44      43
Mon      73      46
Tue      66      67
Wed      54      51
Thu      47      56
Fri      60      47
Sat      41      42
```

If need original ordering use [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
df['col'] = df['Day'].eq(df['Day'].iat[0]).cumsum()
a = df.loc[df['col'] == 1, 'Day']
df = df.set_index(['Day', 'col'])['Total'].unstack()
       .add_prefix('Total')
       .reindex_axis(a, axis=0)
       .reset_index()
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   Day  Total1  Total2
0  Tue      66      67
1  Wed      54      51
2  Thu      47      56
3  Fri      60      47
4  Sat      41      42
5  Sun      44      43
6  Mon      73      46
```

Answer (score 0):

Does not compare with jezrael's solutions but wanted to share a relatively simple method! This solution will not preserve order:

```
pd.pivot(df.Day, df.groupby('Day').cumcount(), df.Total).rename(columns={0: 'Total 1', 1: 'Total 2'}).reset_index()

   Day  Total 1  Total 2
0  Fri       60       47
1  Mon       73       46
2  Sat       41       42
3  Sun       44       43
4  Thu       47       56
5  Tue       66       67
6  Wed       54       51
```